# How can I run a perl script from R with specific modules?

Tags: r, perl

I can run a perl script "myperlscript.pl" from Terminal without any problems. However, if I try to run the same perl script from within RStudio, it gives me the following error:

```
command <- "myperlscript.pl outputfile.txt"

system2('perl', command)

Can't locate Sort/Fields.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Sort::Fields module) 
(@INC contains: 
/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/Library/Perl/5.28 
/Network/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/Network/Library/Perl/5.28 
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.28.2 
/System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/System/Library/Perl/5.28 
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.28) at myperlscript.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at myperlscript.pl line 4.
```

I have the Sort::Fields module installed in /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.26.2/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 and it works fine using Terminal but it seems that perl in RStudio does not index that directory for perl modules - I tried adding it to @INC but somehow I cannot get it to work... any thoughts or ideas? Help is greatly appreciated!

Best, Heiko

Comment: Are you running in Windows or another operating system?

Comment: I am running on MacOs Big Sur

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is that your R Code is using the system perl (5.28) and not your pelbrew perl (5.26.2).

You need to do the `system2('perl', command)` call to use the perlbrew perl instead of the system perl.

To do so from your shell where your perlbrew perl is activated type `which perl` this should give you the full path to your pelbrew perl.

Pass this full path as the first argument to the `system2(--result of 'which perl'--, command)`.