# Problem with mismatched perl binaries using system2 command

Tags: r, perl, command, system

I am trying to run an executable script from within RStudio. The script runs perfectly from Terminal, however, when trying to run it form within R I get the following error message:

```
setwd("/users/admin")
command <- "/users/admin/Test_script.command"
system2(command)

> lib/Bio/DB/HTS/Faidx.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xdb00080, needed 0xc500080)
```

I am running MacOS X Big Sur and I use perlbrew with perl version 5.26.2, I guess the problem is that RStudio tries to use my system perl version - but I couldn't find a way to change that…

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What's the first line of `Test_script.command`?

Comment: Also, even if the wrong `perl` is used, I wouldn't expect that error. Are env vars `PERL5LIB` or `PERLLIB` set?

Comment: Could the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65553736/4253357 help you? Seems to me lie a very similar issue.

Comment: Dear ikegami,

The first line says: 
#! /bin/bash

My ~/.bash_profile file includes:
source $HOME/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
export PERL5LIB=${PERL5LIB}:/bioperl-1.6.924
source $HOME/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
export PATH="$HOME/Library/Python/3.8/bin:$PATH"
export PERL5LIB=${PERL5LIB}:$HOME/bioperl-1.6.924
export PERL5LIB=${PERL5LIB}:$HOME/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.26.2/lib/site_perl/5.2$
/Users/admin/ensembl-vep/vep
export PERL5LIB=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.26.2/lib/site_p$
eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/perl5)"

Comment: Dear Michal,

Thanks for the suggestions - this question was in fact asked by me for another script problem that I was able to solve... Here, however, it somehow does not work - maybe the problem here is, that the script is not a perl script?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get it running by looking into the actual script, which is perl based. Then I was able to solve the problem by following the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/65553736/4253357 as Michal suggested. Thanks again for your help!